# Projectively definable family of sets of reals

Tags: set-theory

Is there a model of set theory in which:

1. Every projectively definable family of sets of reals has an OD or projectively definable member;
2. Every OD or projectively definable set of reals has the property of Baire.

PS: By a projectively definable family of sets of reals I mean:

There exists a formula $\varphi(\Gamma)$ where $\Gamma$ is supposed to be a set of (tuples) of reals and $\mathcal{F}$ is the family of sets defined by: $$\Gamma \in \mathcal{F} \;{\rm iff} \;   \varphi(\Gamma,a)$$
but $\varphi(\Gamma,a) : Q_1 x_1 \dots Q_n x_n Q'_1 z_1 \dots Q'_m z_m \psi(x,z,a,\Gamma)$ with $x$ and $z$ reals and integers respectively, and the $Q_i, Q'_j$ are quantifiers $\in \{ \forall, \exists\}$, $a$ are real parameters. $\psi$ is a $\Delta_0$ formula in the variables $x_i,z_n$ and $\Gamma$.

$\varphi$ and $\psi$ are formulas in the language of arithmetic.

Note that $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ to be precise. An example of $\varphi$ would be:
 $$\forall x \exists y (x,y) \in \Gamma \wedge [\forall z \forall t (((x,z) \in \Gamma) \wedge ((x,t) \in \Gamma)) \rightarrow z=t]$$ ($\Gamma$ is a function, here $x,y,z,t$ are assumed to be real numbers).

Note that $\mathcal{F}$ may have cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ so we cannot parametrize it by reals.

Comment: I would understand your phrase "projectively definable family of sets of reals" to refer to a set of sets of reals consisting of the sections of a projective subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But on this interpretation, property 1 is trivial. So could you say more precisely what you mean?

Comment: @JDH: I edited accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify the formal language more precisely? What kind of assertions are allowed with $\psi$? If you mean that $\psi$ has no further quantifiers, then it seems that you can't say anything much about $\Gamma$ inside $\psi$, or about how it relates to the $x_i$ and $z_j$,  since the elements of $\Gamma$ are sets of reals, but none of the other variables are sets of reals.

Comment: In the first part of your question, $\Gamma$ is described as a set of sets of reals, but in your example, $\Gamma$ consists of pairs of complex numbers. So I still don't really understand what notion of definability you want to consider.

Comment: As with the previous attempt to ask this answer, you should be clearer on some things. Note that "projective sets of reals" are often sets which are definable via a second-order statement in the language of arithmetics; rather than just the language of set theory. When you involve both "sets of reals" and "complex numbers" along with "the language of set theory" you should specify in full what do you mean by real and complex numbers, as well whether or not we are allowed to use the structure of these sets (otherwise, it's just "sets of size continuum" altogether).

Comment: No, I meant $\Gamma$ consists of pairs of complex numbers. Complex numbers are identified with $\mathbb{R}^2$. I hope everything is clear now. $\mathbb{R}$ is identified with ${}^\omega \omega$.

Comment: I am sorry: $\Gamma$ is not a set of sets, it is just a set of pairs of complex numbers. However, my problem is that $\varphi$ does not determine $\Gamma$ completely, so we get a whole family of $\Gamma$'s. $\mathcal{F}$ is the family of sets of pairs of complex numbers.

Comment: The natural interpretation of the question for me would indeed be that there is a relation on the plane that is projective (or OD) and we ask for a projective or OD section, and we moreover ask that projective (or OD) sets have the property of Baire. (In fact, I started to sketch an answer under this interpretation, but classes got in the way. I'll try to find some time to finish the sketch if no other answers appear meanwhile.)

Comment: (And please, do not downvote this.)

Comment: User38200, your new version is more coherent. But one further clarification: your definition as stated does not allow real parameters in your projective definitions; is that what you intended?

Comment: No, you can add as many parameters as you want.

Comment: But every section of a projective subset of a plane is projective, when parameters are allowed, and so statement 1 is trivial.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, the user does not intend what you said (and what I had thought at first with my first comment), a projective subset of the plane. Rather, his notion amounts to a family defined by a projective property considered in second-order logic, as picking out a family of sets.

Comment: That is, what he wants is a projectively expressible property of a set of reals, using a predicate for that set, and the family is all sets of reals with that property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me ignore the OD issue for a moment, and just prove that there is always a projectively definable family of sets of reals, with no projective member. Indeed, there is such a family consisting of a single set.

Namely, let $S$ be the full satisfaction relation on the reals for projective truth. Thus, $S$ consists of all the pairs $(\varphi,x)$, where $\varphi$ is a projective statement and $\varphi(x)$ holds. The set $S$ is not itself projective, for otherwise we could diagonalize against the projective sets by forming the set $\{ n\mid \neg\varphi(n,n)\}$, which would have to be projective, but cannot be defined by any projective formula.

But now the point is that the singleton family ${\cal F}=\{S\}$ is definable by a formula of your type, and is therefore a projectively definable family of sets of reals in the sense of your question. The definition of this family simply notes that $S$ is the only set of pairs that obeys the Tarskian definition of truth, so that it gets the right answer on the atomic formulas, and also does the right thing on Boolean combinations and on quantifiers. That is, the set $S$ exhibits certain internal features — the recursive Tarskian definition of truth — and these features are expressible by quantifying only over integers and reals, provided that we can also refer to membership in $S$ in the expressions.

This example rules out property 1, if one should ask for a projective member of the family. But since projective truth is ordinal definable, it doesn't rule out statement 1 as it is stated, and for this I have to think a bit more.

In any case, if $V=HOD$ then every set is OD, and so any model of $V=HOD$ will satisfy statement 1 in the ordinal-definable version.

Answer (score 5):

Probably "model of set theory" was intended to mean "model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$" but I thought it might be worth mentioning that if we consider models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ then the answer is yes—provided that for (1) we are satisfied with a member that is $\text{OD}_a$ for some real $a$ instead of a $\text{OD}$ member, which is clearly too much to hope for.

Let $M$ be a model of $\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{AD}^+$, for example $M = L(\mathbb{R})$ under the assumption that there are infinitely many Woodin cardinals with a measurable cardinal above them.  Letting $a$ be a real parameter, Woodin's basis theorem for $\Sigma^2_1(a)$ says that every nonempty $\Sigma^2_1(a)$ collection of sets of reals has a $\Delta^2_1(a)$ member.

This is even stronger than the desired result, because on one hand
every projective property can be expressed in a $\Sigma^2_1(a)$ way for some real $a$, and on the other hand every $\Delta^2_1(a)$ set of reals is definable from $a$.

Moreover (2) holds in this model $M$ because the Axiom of Determinacy implies that *every* set has the property of Baire.

Comment: I should mention that for $L(\mathbb{R})$ the basis theorem is due to Solovay, and also that (if we allow real parameters) the model $L(\mathbb{R})$ is a sort of trivial example of (1) because it satisfies "_every_ set is ordinal definable from a real."

Comment: Do you have a reference for Woodin's basis theorem?

Comment: @user38200 See John Steel's paper on the derived model theorem: math.berkeley.edu/~steel/papers/dm.ps, Section 7

Comment: Can't we force the axiom of choice over a model of $ZF+AD^+$ as in a paper by Steel ("Two consequences of determinacy consistent with choice")?

Comment: @user38200 That's right, or if you don't mind CH then you can just force with $\text{Col}(\omega_1,\mathbb{R})$.  I'm not sure what the complexity of the family of non-ground-model sets of reals would be in such models.